# Add class to checkout input when order below €30

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

I'd like to disable the deliver (bezorgen) checkout radiobutton when the order is below €30.There is an other option to pickup yourself and order below 30,- so I think I have to do this with custom script.

The input has id="s_method_flatrate_flatrate" and should be hidden with css (only when below 30 in cart).

Is there a way to do this with JS?
(version 1.7.0.2)

Example of the checkout:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, get the cart total and add it in if condition. like this:

```
<?php
$count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
$total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //get total price
?>
<?php if( $total > 30 ): ?>
    <div class="body free-shipping">
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="body no-free-shipping">
<?php endif; ?>
```

There is no need for $count, but I have added so you can use it if needed.

Comment: hey, thanks, I probably need to add this in the 3columns.phtml template file? Going to test this now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the Table Rate solution to fix this, if you configure the table rate condition as `Price vs. Destination` and build the rate table starting at Euro 30,- then the option isn't displayed when the order is below that value.

Comment: there seems to be some changes, the client tells me when choosing deliver below 30euro then you have to pay 7 euro. (above 30euro there are no delivery costs.) I have no idea how to do this. I will make a new question for this.

Comment: You can use the table rate for this (or use free shipping for orders over 30 euro)